# Removing Duplicate Words from a UITextView

Tags: swift, nsstring, uitextview, nsrange

having this delegate of UItextview i want to remove tagging words that are already in text with this delegate

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {
    if text == " ",let lastWord = textView.text.components(separatedBy: " ").last, lastWord.hasPrefix("@"), let lastWordRange = (textView.text as NSString?)?.range(of: lastWord){
        if self.search(in: lastWord), searchDuplicate(this: lastWord) == 1  {
            let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue, NSFontAttributeName: self.textView.font!] as [String : Any]
            let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: lastWord, attributes: attributes)
            textView.textStorage.replaceCharacters(in:lastWordRange, with:attributedString)

        }else{
            if searchDuplicate(this: lastWord) > 1 {
                textView.text.removeSubrange(Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: textView.text.index(textView.text.endIndex, offsetBy: -lastWord.characters.count ), upper: textView.text.endIndex)))
            }
            let realLW = lastWord.replacingOccurrences(of: "@", with: "")
            textView.textStorage.replaceCharacters(in:lastWordRange, with:realLW)
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

the function dectect a word with @ format and check out if is valid as a tag, but if the tag is input is not the first time it would not get the appropiated format since the range only detecs it in the first apperance so i have to remove it but in the replacing text of the textview.text all word lost their format . so how i can detect the range of the word that is repeated to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
func textView(_ textView: UITextView, shouldChangeTextIn range: NSRange, replacementText text: String) -> Bool {

  if text == " " {
    let newText = removeDuplicates(text: textView.attributedText.string ?? "")
    let attributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.blue, NSFontAttributeName: self.textView.font!] as [String : Any]
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: newText, attributes: attributes)
    textView.attributedText = attributedString
  }
  return true
}

func removeDuplicates(text: String) -> String {
  let words = text.components(separatedBy: " ")
  let filtered = words.filter { $0.characters.first == "@" }
  return Array(Set(filtered)).joined()
}
```

Comment: Just replace with .characters.first